# A HTML tag to store "javascript's data"?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write some html with placeholder used for javascript.

ex:

```
<span><placeholder data-id="42" data-value="abc"/><span>
```

Later on, a script will access those placeholders and put content in (next to?) them.

```
<span><placeholder data-id="42" data-value="abc"><div class="Google"><input type="text" value="abc"/></div><span>
```

But the placeholder tag doesn't exist. What tag can be used? Using < input type="hidden" .../> all over feels wrong.

Comment: Using Hidden fields with unique ID is best way.

Comment: Why not just use JavaScript variables?

Comment: You can store data wherever you want...

Comment: You could put those data attributes on the span and have your JS insert the content as a child

Comment: Why does it matter that “the placeholder tag doesn’t exist”? It will be parsed and it is available, it’s treated as unknown element by browsers. But using invented tags is seldom a good idea, and you should consider a different approach, like simply having an empty `div` with the attributes and then changing its content with a script. (Using `span` here violates HTML rules since you are later inserting a `div` inside it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Creating Custom tag

```
var xFoo = document.createElement('placeholder');
xFoo.innerHTML = "TEST";
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);
```

Output:

```
<placeholder>TEST</placeholder>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2r3bh1tb/)

> **Note:** However creating hidden input fields with unique ID is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

give your span element an id like,

```
<span id="placeToAddItem"><span>
```

and then in jQuery,

```
$('#placeToAddItem').html('<div class="Google"><input type="text" value="abc"/></div>');
```

or else

```
var cloneDiv = $('.Google');
$('#placeToAddItem').html(cloneDiv);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/hq53nbLg/14/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is using `<input type='hidden' id="someId" value="">` tags.
Then you can easily access them by using jQuery, and recall the variable or change it.
`var value = $("#someId").val();` to get variable or `$("#someId").val(value)` to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This complete, no jQuery solution allows you to specify the placeholder/replacement html as a string *within* the element that will be replaced.

**EG HTML:**

```
<div data-placeholder="<div class='Google'><input type='text' value='abc'/></div>"></div>
<div data-placeholder="<div class='Boogle'><input type='text' value='def'/></div>"></div>
<div data-placeholder="<div class='Ooogle'><label>with label <input type='text' value='ghi'/></label></div>"></div>
<span data-placeholder="<em>Post JS</em>">Pre JS</span>
<br />
<button id="test">click me</button>
```

**JS:**

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to select all elements with the attribute 'data-placeholder' (returns a NodeList)

```
var placeholders = document.querySelectorAll('[data-placeholder]'); //or by ids, classnames, element type etc
```

Extend the NodeList prototype with a simple 'each' method that allows us to iterate over the list.

```
NodeList.prototype.each = function(func) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        func(this[i]);
    }
    return this;//return self to maintain chainability
};
```

Extend the Object prototype with a 'replaceWith' method that replaces the element with a new one created from a html string:

```
Object.prototype.replaceWith = function(htmlString) {
    var temp = document.createElement('div');//create a temporary element
        temp.innerHTML = htmlString;//set its innerHTML to htmlString
    var newChild = temp.childNodes[0];//(or temp.firstChild) get the inner nodes
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, this);//replace old node with new
    return this;//return self to maintain chainability
};
```

Put it all together:

```
placeholders.each(function(self){
   self.replaceWith(self.dataset.placeholder);//the 'data-placeholder' string
});
```

Another example but here we only replace one specific element with some hard-coded html on click:

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click', function() {
   this.replaceWith("<strong>i was a button before</strong>");
}, false);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sjbnn68e/

Answer (score -1):

use the code below :

```
var x = document.createElement('placeholder');

x.innerHTML = "example";

document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Comment: Serge stated that the tag does not exist and has asked `What tag can be used?`. And based on the next part `Using < input type="hidden" .../> all over feels wrong.` he is looking for recommendations which specific tag `<input>`, `<div>` or [data-tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element) to use. You are not answering this question. Please elaborate your answer.